# invoke lambda function in iOS appDelegate didReceiveRemoteNotification when app is in background

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, aws-lambda, remote-notifications

I am trying to fetch data by invoking a lambda function in response to a remote push notification while my app is in the background.  My notifications are configured correctly and the didReceiveRemoteNotification is called while the app is in the background.

I have the following code in that method:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()


    lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("lambdaFunctionName", jsonObject: jsonObject).continueWith(block: {(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print(task.error!.localizedDescription)
            print(task.error!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if (error.domain == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorDomain) && (AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType.functionError == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType(rawValue: error.code)) {
                    print("Function error: \(String(describing: error.userInfo[AWSLambdaInvokerFunctionErrorKey]))")
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                }
            })
            return nil
        }
        // Handle response in task.result
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let jsonArray = task.result as? NSArray {
                // do stuff
            }
        })
        return nil
    })
}
```

However the block is not executed in the lambda function.  I have not used background fetch before and not sure how to make this work with a lambda function.

Answer (score 1):

What I was missing was the completion handler.  After adding that, the code and block executes as expected:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable : Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {
    let lambdaInvoker = AWSLambdaInvoker.default()


    lambdaInvoker.invokeFunction("lambdaFunctionName", jsonObject: jsonObject).continueWith(block: {(task:AWSTask<AnyObject>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            print(task.error!.localizedDescription)
            print(task.error!)
            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
                if (error.domain == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorDomain) && (AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType.functionError == AWSLambdaInvokerErrorType(rawValue: error.code)) {
                    print("Function error: \(String(describing: error.userInfo[AWSLambdaInvokerFunctionErrorKey]))")
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                } else {
                    print("Error: \(error)")
                    completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
                }
            })
            return nil
        }
        // Handle response in task.result
        DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
            if let jsonArray = task.result as? NSArray {
                // do stuff
                completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResult.newData)
            }
        })

        return nil
    })
}
```